# Delete Row in UITableView but dont use Delete button

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a problem, I want to delete row in UITableView but don't use swipe button delete. I want call function `removeCell` after condition. My problem is I cannot delete first row in UITableView because I don't know get indexPath of row to delete.

If I swipe Delete button, it work perfect. **But I want don't use Delete Button.**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    deleteindexPath = indexPath;
    /*[_tableView beginUpdates];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    [_tableView endUpdates];*/
    [self removeCell];
}
```

removeCell():

```
    -(void) removeCell
{
    [_tableView beginUpdates];

        [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:deleteIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   // }
    [_tableView endUpdates];
}
```

I try set  `deleteIndexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:cell];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` but not work, crash.

Can you have suggestion?

Comment: Then How you want to call this `removeCell ` method

Comment: And how may sections do you have?

Comment: Which array you use to populate tableview?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
-(void) removeCell
{    
    [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:deleteIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    //Now remove data from your tableArray also..
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```